# If element is not present skip to next step in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using java `try` and `catch`. 
If the element is not present I need to skip to the next step

I tried the following inside the `try` block:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But got the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

Comment: so did u `try` to `catch` that error message?

Comment: Post the code which you tried. Then only we can say where you made the mistake.

Comment: i tried but not worked, i need like if present true or false

Comment: That errors seems to come from you finding the element and trying to click on it or write to it when it isn't visible, provide code please

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id of the element to be located")));
    return SUCCESS;
} catch (NoSuchElementException exception) {
    return FAILURE;
}
```

If return is `SUCCESS` then execute next line else skip it.

Comment: You probably want to catch `TimeOutException` (not sure of the name there) as well :)

Comment: Not exactely, Just verfying that if element is present in specified limit or not and if not then skip.
For more clarification instead of return SUCCESS and return FAILURE, you can return true or return false.
if return is true then execute next line else skip it.

Comment: When using an explicit wait: "This waits up to [x] seconds before throwing a TimeoutException" (http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). Catching `NoSuchElementException` will not help you